# uploading an audio blob into a folder using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, blob

I'm building a record voice project and I want to upload the audio in a folder (upload) through a blob.
this is what I have achieved so far:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var li = document.createElement('li');
var au = document.createElement('audio');
var hf = document.createElement('a');

au.controls = true;
au.src = url;
hf.href = url;
hf.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
li.appendChild(au);
li.appendChild(hf);


fileName=hf.download;
console.log(fileName);
var data = new FormData();
data.append(url, blob);

$.ajax({
  url :  "upload.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  }
});
```

and this is the php code for the ajax function (upload.php):

```
<?php

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["fileName"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$fileName=$_POST['fileName'];

if ($_FILES["fileName"]["error"] > 0) {
console.log( "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileName"]["error"] . "<br>");
} else {


if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["fileName"]["name"])) {
  console.log( $_FILES["fileName"]["name"] . " already exists. ");
} else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["fileName"]["name"]);

}
}
?>
```

when debbuging the audio is not saved in the folder upload and the following error is obtained : Undefined index: fileName in upload.php
what is going wrong with my code???please help

Comment: I am having the same problem. As far as I can tell it just plain doesn't work.